# What is the effect of demshutdown() function on FiM? In AUTOSAR?

Tags: autosar

The team wants to shut down the DEM component in AUTOSAR temprarily for some processing inside FiM, the question is will it affect any functionality of FiM by any chance?

If Yes then How?

Is there any other way of stopping the reporting of DTSc into FiM temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, this is not correct solution. Problems which I see now:

- reset of internal data not stored in Nvm (debounce counters and operation cycles)
- needs to called Nvm_WriteAll or Nvm_Write for block used by DEM
- when DEM is deinitialized diagnostic services with SID 0x19 and 0x14 will return NRC10

I think better solution is configure one additional *DemEnableCondition* and add to every *DemEnableConditionGroups*. Every DTC shall have one of this *DemEnableConditionGroup*.

This condition shall be handled by FIM. If we want stop reporting DTCs, FIM will set status of this condition to FALSE and after processing value could be switch back to TRUE, which unblock reporting DTCs.